# What is the difference between retzev and a combo?

Tags: terminology, krav-maga, striking

The concept of retzev (in krav maga) is kind of vague to me at the moment, and I'm wondering if there is a difference between retzev and a normal trained combo (in other martial arts).

Is it that the strikes in retzev are not pre-arranged like those in a combo? Or are there other major differences?

Comment: Plenty of videos on youtube showing it and explaining it. I just watched some and pretty much got the answer. Combos are a part of retzev. But the main thing about retzev is to continuously strike an opponent, using techniques that continuously cause him to reveal holes in his defense which you then target. Its goal is to overwhelm an opponent. Combos can be part of it, but you base your attack on his reaction to your previous attack. You're not going in with a predetermined combination, in other words. My interpretation based on what I saw in those videos.

Comment: @SteveWeigand Please write an answer.

Comment: @mattm I'll leave that to an actual krav maga practitioner. Hopefully someone will chime in. Watching a video for a few minutes on Youtube doesn't make me authoritative. Haha.

Comment: @SteveWeigand I dunno... I hear getting licensed is really easy in the United States...

Comment: @MacacoBranco Oh no you d'nt! :) Haha. No, we love our Krav Maga friends. Don't send any Israeli snipers out to get us. Please. Haha.

Comment: Online course licensing is definitely not exclusive to Krav Maga but it is more common there for sure.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I still remember the controversy over online BJJ certification. And, of course, it can be hard to trademark a martial art to prevent others from teaching their own version.